# RSpec test fails with NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have a model `domain.rb`

```
class Domain < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :ranks, dependent: :destroy

  validates_uniqueness_of :name, scope: :user_id, message: "You alredy entered that domain"
  validates_presence_of :name
  validate :user_quota, on: :create

  def user_quota
    errors.add(:base, 'OOps!!! You have Exceeded maximum domain limit/user (3)')  if self.user.domains(:reload).count >= 3
  end
end
```

In my `domain_spec.rb` I am trying to test the custom validation - *There can be only 3 domains for a unique user*

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Domain, type: :model do
  it " - cannot create a new domain if user already have 3 domains" do

    user = User.create(name: "John Doe", email: 'jane@doe.com', password: 'pw1234',
    password_confirmation: 'pw1234')

    user_domain1 = Domain.create(name: 'http://example1.com', user_id: user.id,
               created_at: DateTime.now, updated_at: DateTime.now)
    expect(user_domain1.errors).to be_empty

    user_domain2 = Domain.create(name: 'http://example2.com', user_id: user.id,
               created_at: DateTime.now, updated_at: DateTime.now)
    expect(user_domain2.errors).to be_empty

    user_domain3 = Domain.create(name: 'http://example3.com', user_id: user.id,
               created_at: DateTime.now, updated_at: DateTime.now)
    expect(user_domain3.errors).to be_empty

    user_domain4 = Domain.create(name: 'http://example4.com', user_id: user.id,
               created_at: DateTime.now, updated_at: DateTime.now)
    expect(user_domain4.errors).to_not be_empty

  end
end
```

when running my test `rspec spec/models/domain_spec.rb` I am getting error:

> Domain  - cannot create a new domain if user already have 3 domains
>
> ```
>  Failure/Error: errors.add(:base, 'OOps!!! You have Exceeded maximum
>  domain limit/user (3)')  if self.user.domains(:reload).count >= 3
>  NoMethodError: undefined method `domains' for nil:NilClass
> ```

my `user.rb`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :domains
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
       :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable, :lockable, :zxcvbnable

  # Override Devise method to send mails in background
  def send_devise_notification(notification, *args)
    devise_mailer.send(notification, self, *args).deliver_later
  end
end
```

What am I doing wrong? I am new to RSpec, please do help me figure out this issue. thanks in advance

Comment: Did you add `has_many :domains` into your `User` model?

Comment: @Uzbekjon yes I have `has_many :domains` in user.rb

Comment: Not directly related to the error you're getting, but what is `:reload` supposed to do in `self.user.domains(:reload).count`?

Comment: try assigning the whole user object when creating domains, not just id. `Domain.create(user: user)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the error message:

```
[...] self.user.domains(:reload).count >= 3
  NoMethodError: undefined method `domains' for nil:NilClass
```

This indicates that the `user` was not saved, presumably because of some validation error(s). The challenge now is to find out *why* the validation is failing, so you can fix it.

In your test code, you are creating these database entries as follows:

```
user = User.create(name: "John Doe", ...)
user_domain1 = Domain.create(name: 'http://example1.com', user_id: user.id, ...)
```

A simple way to pick up on what error is occurring, so that your test fails with a more helpful message, is to use [`create!` instead of `create`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence/ClassMethods.html#method-i-create):

```
user = User.create!(name: "John Doe", ...)
user_domain1 = Domain.create!(name: 'http://example1.com', user_id: user.id, ...)
```

By doing this, an `RecordInvalid` exception will be raised, stating the reason why the record could not be saved.

Comment: Something else you may wish to look into using, to make your tests simpler, is to create data via a factory pattern - e.g. using [`factory_girl`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl) (and `factory_girl_rails`).